# Merge multiple JSON arrays without changing the sequence in Dataweave 1.0

Tags: json, mule, transform, dataweave, mulesoft

I have a couple of JSON arrays which I need to combine before I send it to Public API as input payload and I would like the payloads stay in the sequence as how I specify them in the dataweave but how can I do it in Dataweave 1.0? Each of my JSON array is large dataset and has many attributes for each record, I notice the data is jumbled up across all arrays after concatenation. How can I fix this?

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
payload[0] ++ payload[1] ++ payload[2] ++ payload[3] ++ payload[4]
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear exactly what is not working for you or what are the payloads in your example, but just concatenating the array works.

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
%var array1 = [1,2,3,4]
%var array2 = [5,6,7,8]
---
array1 ++ array2
```

Output

```
[
  1,
  2,
  3,
  4,
  5,
  6,
  7,
  8
]
```

Comment: When it involves larger dataset and there's many attributes in each item in the arrays, I notice the data is jumbled up :(

Comment: How big are the arrays and how many attributes has each element?

Comment: Each array has about 2K items and each item has about 20 attributes, total 10K items to be sent to the Public API at a time.

Answer (score 0):

The only way you're going to be able to consistently ensure the order is to have a clause in which you order the data. Which I'm not sure you have based off the information you provided but would look something similar to:

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
%var data = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
---
data reduce ((item, acc=[]) -> acc ++ (item orderBy $))
```